# Copy multiple files, archive and name the archive with date and hour in Powershell

Tags: date, timestamp, powershell-ise

I have this bit of a code:

```
$sursa_folder="C:\folder\folder\folder\folder"
$sursa_file="file"

$dest_folder="F:\+\name\Dump"

Copy-Item (Join-Path $sursa_folder $sursa_file) -Destination $dest_folder
try {Compress-Archive -Path (Join-Path $dest_folder $sursa_file) -CompressionLevel Optimal -DestinationPath ((Join-Path $dest_folder $sursa_file) + (Get-Date).ToString('ddMMyyyy-hh.mm.ss') + ".zip") -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
#Compress-Archive -Path (Join-Path $dest_folder $sursa_file) -CompressionLevel Optimal -DestinationPath ("X:\" + (Get-Date).ToString('ddMMyyyy-hh.mm.ss') + ".zip") -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue Remove-Item (Join-Path $dest_folder $sursa_file) -Force -ErrorAction Stop Write-Host "finalizat OK"
}
catch {
write-host "Eroare: $_"
}
finally {

}
```

And I want to add more files into the same archive. How do I do that?

I was thinking of something of this:

```
$sursa_folder="C:\folder\folder\folder\folder"
$sursa_file="file1""file2""file3""file4""file5""file6""file7"

$dest_folder="F:\+\name\Dump"

Copy-Item (Join-Path $sursa_folder $sursa_file) -Destination $dest_folder
try {
Compress-Archive -Path (Join-Path $dest_folder $sursa_file) -CompressionLevel Optimal -DestinationPath ((Join-Path $dest_folder $sursa_file) + (Get-Date).ToString('ddMMyyyy-hh.mm.ss') + ".zip") -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
#Compress-Archive -Path (Join-Path $dest_folder $sursa_file) -CompressionLevel Optimal -DestinationPath ("X:\" + (Get-Date).ToString('ddMMyyyy-hh.mm.ss') + ".zip") -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Remove-Item (Join-Path $dest_folder $sursa_file) -Force -ErrorAction Stop
Write-Host "finalizat OK"
}
catch {
write-host "Eroare: $_"
}
finally {

}
```

But to no avail ...

Thank you reader for your time.

L.E.: Now the finish result.

```
# this function will zip an entire folder (in your case the destination folder)
function ZipFiles( $zipfilename, $sourcedir )
{
   Add-Type -Assembly System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
   $compressionLevel = [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Optimal
   [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($sourcedir,$zipfilename, $compressionLevel, $false)
}

$sursa_folder="C:\folder\folder\folder\folder"
$sursa_file=@("file1","file2","file3","file4","file5","file6","file7") # <= eaxample name files, rename as needed.
$dest_folder= "F:\+\name\Dump"
$folderName = "File_Folder" # <= rename as needed.
$destinationfolder =  New-Item -Path (Join-Path $dest_folder $folderName) -ItemType Directory

foreach($file in $sursa_file)
{
Copy-Item (Join-Path $sursa_folder $file) -Destination (Join-Path $dest_folder $folderName) # this copies the item from source to destination >> destination is a folder within the destination
#Now you will have multiple files ("file1","file2","file3","file4","file5","file6","file7") that are copied from source to a destination folder
}

try {
ZipFiles -sourcedir (Join-Path $dest_folder $folderName) -zipfilename ((Join-Path $dest_folder $folderName) + (Get-Date).ToString('ddMMyyyy-hh.mm.ss') + ".zip") # zip the destination folder and give it a new name
Remove-Item -Path (Join-Path $dest_folder $folderName) -Force -ErrorAction Stop -Recurse -Confirm:$false # this will delete the unzipped old folder 
Write-Host "finalizat OK"
}
catch {
write-host "Eroare: $_"
}
finally {}
```

Thank you very much Clint Oliveira, i wouldn't managed without your help. :)

Comment: It's an **archive** - not an "arhive" ...

Comment: what happens when you run your code. Does it not work? 
you have "-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue", try removing this and let me know if there is an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 > I want to give a permanent name to that folder. Change `File_Folder` to the folder name you desire.

- Replace `$folderName = Read-Host "Please Enter the folder Name"` with `$folderName = "File_Folder"`

2 > i don't want PowerShell to ask me for my confirmation if i want to remove the children with item with all.

- Modify the `Remove-item` line to:
  `Remove-Item -Path (Join-Path $dest_folder $folderName) -Force -ErrorAction Stop -Recurse -Confirm:$false`

3 > where do i find this documentation for PS? I mean, i tried to google for $folderName = and found almost nothing. Only other people asking different questions. I know that in cmd (i think ... if i'm not wrong) you can use the ? or the tab key (i think) and you can get a list of possible commands. How do i check with PS?

- PowerShell Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/
- list of possible commands > use the "**Tab Key**" however you need to type the verb eg. `get-` or `set-` etc this snip is from PowerShell ISE
  [image]

Comment: Remove-Item -Path (Join-Path $dest_folder $folderName) -Force -ErrorAction Stop -Recurse -Confirm:$false
  # Please delete the path in your comment.. its a local path should not be on the internet. Much Appreciated

Comment: Works fine but i get this at the delete stage: Cannot find path 'C:\folder\folder_Sync\folder' because it does not exist. What it is C:\folder\folder_Sync\folder or trix for that matter? Tried to google search it ...

Comment: The delete command is trying to delete the folder that got converted to a zip file in the destination.

Comment: its trying to find the folder "(Join-Path $dest_folder $folderName)", so that it can delete it.

Remove-Item -Path (Join-Path $dest_folder $folderName) -Force -ErrorAction Stop -Recurse -Confirm:$false

Answer (score 2):

Consider converting your `$sursa_file` variable to an array and then do a `foreach ($file in $sursa_file)` like so:

```
$sursa_file=@("file1","file2","file3","file4","file5","file6","file7")
```

You are getting an error because `Join-Path $sursa_folder $sursa_file`
is trying to query [image]

If you convert `$sursa_file` to an array and do a `foreach-object` then it will look for the right file path each time in loops though you variable so `Join-Path $sursa_folder $sursa_file` becomes [image]

Here is my attempt: You can fill in the catch/finally actions on your own.

```
# this function will zip an entire folder (in your case the destination folder)
function ZipFiles( $zipfilename, $sourcedir )
{
   Add-Type -Assembly System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
   $compressionLevel = [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Optimal
   [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($sourcedir,$zipfilename, $compressionLevel, $false)
}

$sursa_folder="C:\folder\folder\folder\folder"
$sursa_file=@("file1","file2","file3","file4","file5","file6","file7")
$dest_folder= "F:\+\name\Dump"
$folderName = Read-Host "Please Enter the folder Name"
$destinationfolder =  New-Item -Path (Join-Path $dest_folder $folderName) -ItemType Directory

foreach($file in $sursa_file)
{
Copy-Item (Join-Path $sursa_folder $file) -Destination (Join-Path $dest_folder $folderName) # this copies the item from source to destination >> destination is a folder within the destination
#Now you will have multiple files ("file1","file2","file3","file4","file5","file6","file7") that are copied from source to a destination folder
}

try {
ZipFiles -sourcedir (Join-Path $dest_folder $folderName) -zipfilename ((Join-Path $dest_folder $folderName) + (Get-Date).ToString('ddMMyyyy-hh.mm.ss') + ".zip") # zip the destination folder and give it a new name
Remove-Item (Join-Path $dest_folder $folderName) -Force -ErrorAction Stop # this will delete the unzipped old folder 
Write-Host "finalizat OK"
}
catch {
write-host "Eroare: $_"
}
finally {}
```

Comment: Ok, this works ... kinda ... But how do i put all the files in the same zip file?

I mean i want to take @("file1","file2","file3","file4","file5","file6","file7") and put them in the same zip withowt zip for each file, i don't want to have separete zips ... Does this make any sense for you?

Thank you very much for the insight of PwerShell.

Comment: move your try, catch, finally out of the for-each loop and compress the destination location. >> I have edited the script.. check if that works

Comment: I think we need to name that file in somewhat way in the > Compress-Archive -Path $dest_folder <. I belive that was doing this: Compress-Archive -Path (Join-Path $dest_folder $file), was taking a name from file that wanted to zip it and made a zip out of that name. And i don't know why, but the last file is not copying it, although it appears in "result" test-run.

Comment: @BogdanNicolescu I have edited the script to meet your requirements. I have added comments to it to guide you. Hope this answers your questions and meets your requirements. What are you looking to name the zip file?

Comment: The current script will use the name of the destination folder using > $dest_folder.Split("\")[-1]

Comment: Now it's doing something ... And the keyword is something. Maybe i'm a nut head and i don't get this pwershell scripting too easy, but how do i tell to pwershell to make a folder 'Inside' the 'Dump' folder so it leaves alone the 'Dump' folder? Thnak you.

Comment: what would you like the folder inside the destination folder named? We can create a folder in the Dest location. Then copy all the files to that folder, Zip it with a name that has date and time and then delete the original unzipped folder
I have modified the script again. It will ask you for a folder name in the dest folder. You can modify that bit if you want a different folder name within dest.

Comment: It works ... kinda. Kinda good. But ... 1 i want to give a permanent name to that folder  and 2 i don't want powershell to ask me for my confirmation if i want to remove the children with item with all. And 3, where do i find this documentation for PS? I mean, i tried to google for $folderName = and found almost nothing. Only other people asking different questions. I know that in cmd (i think ... if i'm not wrong) you can use the ? or the tab key (i think) and you can get a list of possible commands. How do i check with PS?

Comment: hope the 2nd comment answered the 3 questions